# How to return an array of objects using Express, Node JS & Angular via a HTTP Get request

Tags: node.js, angular, express

I've replicated this tutorial https://malcoded.com/posts/angular-backend-express/ to set up an angular app & an express server w/ Node.js

I'm now trying to send a GET request to retrieve an array of objects with the following code:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CatService } from './cat/cat.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'malcodedTutorial';
  constructor(private catSerivce: CatService) { }

  cats = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    const catsObservable = this.catSerivce.getAllCats();
    catsObservable.subscribe((catsData: []) => {
        this.cats = catsData;
    });
    console.log(this.cats);
  }
}
```

Also, here is the server.js file:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors')

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200 
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('Server started!')
});

// GET ALL CATS
app.route('/api/cats').get((req, res) => {
  res.send({
    cats: [{ name: 'lilly' }, { name: 'lucy' }],
  })
})

// GET A SPECIFIC CAT
app.route('/api/cats/:name').get((req, res) => {
  const requestedCatName = req.params['name']
  res.send({ name: requestedCatName })
})

const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.route('/api/cats').post((req, res) => {
  res.send(201, req.body)
})

// UPDATE
app.route('/api/cats/:name').put((req, res) => {
  res.send(200, req.body)
})

// DELETE
app.route('/api/cats/:name').delete((req, res) => {
  res.sendStatus(204)
})
```

Also, here is my Cat Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

interface Cat {
  name: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CatService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getAllCats(): Observable<Cat[]> {
    return this.http.get<Cat[]>('http://localhost:8000/api/cats');
  }

  getCat(name: string): Observable<Cat> {
    return this.http.get<Cat>('http://localhost:8000/api/cats/' +   name);
  }

  insertCat(cat: Cat): Observable<Cat> {
    return this.http.post<Cat>('http://localhost:8000/api/cats/', cat);
  }

  updateCat(cat: Cat): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.put<void>(
      'http://localhost:8000/api/cats/' + cat.name,
      cat
    );
  }

  deleteCat(name: string) {
    return this.http.delete('http://localhost:8000/api/cats/' + name);
  }
}
```

When I run the Angular app, the page is displaying as expected, & there are no errors in the console.

There is an empty array being logged to the console, I don't know why the app isn't picking up the cat objects from server.js.

Can someone please tell me where I am going wrong? Much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code for getting a response from the server is correct. The reason it is logging an empty array is because your console.log is not inside of the subscription. Since the observable is operating asynchronously it is logging before the response is received. If you want it to console.log only after the response is received then move it inside of your .subscribe()

If you change your ngOnInit() to look like this you won't console.log until the response is received so it should not be empty anymore, unless the response doesn't contain any cats.

```
ngOnInit() {
    const catsObservable = this.catSerivce.getAllCats();
    catsObservable.subscribe((catsData: []) => {
        this.cats = catsData;
        console.log(this.cats);
    });
}
```

This would also work:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'malcodedTutorial';
  constructor(private catSerivce: CatService) { }

  cats = [];

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getCats();
  }

  getCats() {
    const catsObservable = this.catSerivce.getAllCats();
    catsObservable.subscribe((catsData: any[]) => {
      this.cats = catsData;
      console.log(this.cats);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you never get data from the server.

in your cat service

```
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';


getAllCats() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Authorization': `Bearer test}`
    });
    const options = { headers: headers };
    const url     = 'http://localhost:8000/api/cats';
    return this.http.get<Cat[]>(url, options);
}
```

first, you must ensure that you get some data and the list is not empty in the console.

Else if you get the data, and in your template, there is nothing showing, then try after view init

You must add the ngAfterViewInit

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  title = 'malcodedTutorial';
  constructor(private catSerivce: CatService) { }

  cats = [];

  ngOnInit() {
     this.getCats();
  }


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.getCats();
  }


  getCats() {
    const catsObservable = this.catSerivce.getAllCats();
    catsObservable.subscribe((catsData: any[]) => {
      this.cats = catsData;
    });
    console.log(this.cats);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I've tried your code, but now the empty array is logged to the console twice

Comment: yes know we now that your server never returns data, this is the first step

Comment: if you go to the http://localhost:8000/api/cats  you see any data??

Comment: Yes, the 2 cat objects from _server.js_ are displayed

Comment: that's ok now we know the server works.

Comment: Great, so what changes do I need to make to actually retrieve that data from the server?

Comment: Now should work, you forget the headers

Comment: I've updated my code with your answer, but I'm still getting two empty arrays when I load _http://localhost:4200/_

Comment: Your question looks very nice, I dont know why you dont get your data, spend more time on this, in the end, you will find the answer.